# Turbo-rails keeps CSS loaded from the previous page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo-rails

I'm using turbo-rails 1.1.1 with Rails 7. I have two pages: first includes Tailwind css, second uses Bootstrap:

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="tailwind.css">
</head>
```

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
</head>
```

When the user navigates from Tailwind page to the Bootstrap, the page now includes both styles, which breaks the styling:

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="tailwind.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
</head>
```

It looks like turbo-rails keeps all the CSS links from the previous page.

**Question 1**: Is it expected behaviour?

**Question 2**: Is there a way to prevent turbo-rails from keeping CSS links from previous pages?

Comment: Have you checked this https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#reloading-when-assets-change and this https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#ensuring-specific-pages-trigger-a-full-reload

Comment: @Maxence Thanks, yes I'm currently using "data-turbo-track" attribute on `<link>` css elements. The `<meta content="reload">` is not what I want, since I still want a fast fetch loading of content instead of forcing full reload.